# Action support Rerender not working

Tags: visualforce, rerender

I want to render the second `pageBlockSectionItem` when the stage of the picklist named "StageName" is "Lead Qualified"

My tags:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="GeoGradeSelectionController">

  <apex:sectionHeader title="Lead" subtitle="{!Opportunity.Name}"/>

  <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Lead Edit" id="pb" mode="edit">

      <apex:pageBlockSection title="General Information">
      <!-- FIRST PICKLIST WITH OPTION Lead Qualified -->
        <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.StageName}">
           <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="LeadQualified"/>
        </apex:inputField> 

        <!-- SECOND PICKLIST TO RENDER ID STAGENAME="Lead Qualified" -->
       <apex:pageBlockSectionItem rendered="{!opportunity.stageName == 'Lead Qualified'}" id="LeadQualified">
           <apex:outputLabel value="Lead Qualified RecordType"/>
            <apex:outputPanel styleClass="requiredInput" layout="block" id="pwPanel"> 
            <apex:outputPanel styleClass="requiredBlock"/> 
            <apex:selectList value="{!Opportunity.LeadQualifiedRecordType__c}" size="1" required="true" multiselect="false">
                  <apex:selectOption itemValue="Opportunity" itemLabel="Opportunity"/>
                  <apex:selectOption itemValue="Proactive Selling Opportunity" itemLabel="Proactive Selling"/>  
            </apex:selectList> 
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>  
      </apex:pageBlockSection>

    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

The rerender for component with id="LeadQualified" is not working.
Do you know why?

**UPDATE**:second version according to Ralph´s answer:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="GeoGradeSelectionController">

  <apex:sectionHeader title="Lead" subtitle="{!Opportunity.Name}"/>

  <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Lead Edit" id="pb" mode="edit">

      <apex:pageBlockSection title="General Information">
      <!-- FIRST PICKLIST WITH OPTION Lead Qualified -->
        <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.StageName}">
           <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="pb"/>
        </apex:inputField> 

        <!-- SECOND PICKLIST TO RENDER ID STAGENAME="Lead Qualified" -->

         <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Name}"/>
         <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Probability}"/>
         <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.AccountId}" required="true"/> 
            <apex:selectList value="{!Opportunity.LeadQualifiedRecordType__c}" size="1" required="true" multiselect="false" rendered="{!opportunity.stageName == 'Lead Qualified'}">
                  <apex:selectOption itemValue="Opportunity" itemLabel="Opportunity"/>
                  <apex:selectOption itemValue="Proactive Selling Opportunity" itemLabel="Proactive Selling"/>  
            </apex:selectList> 

      </apex:pageBlockSection>

    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

It's still not working, please help me again.

**UPDATE 2**: solution according Nick.

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="GeoGradeSelectionController">
<apex:sectionHeader title="Lead" subtitle="{!Opportunity.Name}"/>

  <apex:form >
  <apex:pageBlock title="Lead Edit" id="pb" mode="edit">

  <apex:pageBlockSection title="General Information">
    <!-- FIRST PICKLIST WITH OPTION Lead Qualified -->
    <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.StageName}">
       <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="LeadQualified"/>
    </apex:inputField> 

    <!-- SECOND PICKLIST TO RENDER ID STAGENAME="Lead Qualified" -->
    <apex:outputPanel id="LeadQualified">
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem rendered="{!opportunity.stageName == 'Lead Qualified'}" >
       <apex:outputLabel value="Lead Qualified RecordType"/>
        <apex:outputPanel styleClass="requiredInput" layout="block" id="pwPanel"> 
        <apex:outputPanel styleClass="requiredBlock"/> 
        <apex:selectList value="{!Opportunity.LeadQualifiedRecordType__c}" size="1" required="true" multiselect="false">
              <apex:selectOption itemValue="Opportunity" itemLabel="Opportunity"/>
              <apex:selectOption itemValue="Proactive Selling Opportunity" itemLabel="Proactive Selling"/>  
        </apex:selectList> 
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
   </apex:outputPanel>
  </apex:pageBlockSection>

</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

It´s working but it is giving wrong style to the field "LeadQualifiedRecordType":
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I used: re-render the entire pageBlock ("pb") instead of trying to re-render just the one inputField.

```
<apex:pageBlock title="Lead Edit" id="pb" mode="edit">
  <apex:pageBlockSection title="General Information">
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
      <apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.Opportunity.fields.StageName.label}" />
      <apex:actionRegion>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.StageName}">
          <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="pb" />
        </apex:inputField>
      </apex:actionRegion>
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem rendered="{!opportunity.stageName == 'Lead Qualified'}">
      <apex:outputLabel value="Lead Qualified RecordType" />
      <apex:outputPanel styleClass="requiredInput" layout="block" id="pwPanel">
        <apex:selectList value="{!Opportunity.LeadQualifiedRecordType__c}" size="1" required="true" multiselect="false">
          <apex:selectOption itemValue="Opportunity" itemLabel="Opportunity" />
          <apex:selectOption itemValue="Proactive Selling Opportunity" itemLabel="Proactive Selling" />
        </apex:selectList>
      </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
  </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Answer (score 8):

You've fallen into a tricky gotcha with re-rendering. When the re-render is processed, only the children of the re-rendered component or re-processed. Hence the your `{!opportunity.stageName === 'Lead Qualified'}` statement isn't re-evaluated and the section isn't shown.

The solution is to re-render the parent of the section having the conditional changed. Looking at your page a good candidate would be to render the pageblock with id `pb`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ralph! I have updated my question with the version of my code according your solution. It´s still not working. Please could you have a look again? Thanks again.

Comment: @Enry if you're having a different issue, please post a separate question. The usefulness of your question for future users is diminished if you have multiple followups, and you'll get more rep with multiple questions.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Ralph's answer, through trial and error I found that rerendering needed to be done on an `outputPanel` rather than other elements.  It was a solution that worked for me, not sure if it will work across the board, but worth a try nonetheless.

Try wrapping the pageBlockSectionItem in an outputPanel.

i.e.

```
<apex:pageBlock title="Lead Edit" id="pb" mode="edit">

  <apex:pageBlockSection title="General Information">
  <!-- FIRST PICKLIST WITH OPTION Lead Qualified -->
    <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.StageName}">
       <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="LeadQualified"/>
    </apex:inputField> 

    <!-- SECOND PICKLIST TO RENDER ID STAGENAME="Lead Qualified" -->
    <apex:outputPanel id="LeadQualified">
   <apex:pageBlockSectionItem rendered="{!opportunity.stageName == 'Lead Qualified'}" >
       <apex:outputLabel value="Lead Qualified RecordType"/>
        <apex:outputPanel styleClass="requiredInput" layout="block" id="pwPanel"> 
        <apex:outputPanel styleClass="requiredBlock"/> 
        <apex:selectList value="{!Opportunity.LeadQualifiedRecordType__c}" size="1" required="true" multiselect="false">
              <apex:selectOption itemValue="Opportunity" itemLabel="Opportunity"/>
              <apex:selectOption itemValue="Proactive Selling Opportunity" itemLabel="Proactive Selling"/>  
        </apex:selectList> 
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
   </apex:outputPanel>
  </apex:pageBlockSection>

</apex:pageBlock>
```

Note:  I moved the `id="LeadQualified"` from the pageBlockSectionItem to the outputPanel.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your inputs Nick! It´s working the rerender now but it´s giving wrong style to the field. I´ve updated my question, please could you give a look?

Comment: Yep, that'll work, the only thing that matters for the re-render to re-evaluate a `render` attribute is that it's a parent of the element with the `render` attribute. But I'm guessing the output panel is what's breaking the styling since you want the `pageblocksectionitem` to be a child of a `pageblocksection` not an `outputpanel`

Comment: Hi Ralf, i guess is the same question. Nick´s solution is not working, like you said i want to rerender a pageblocksectionitem or a pageblocksection keeping the style. Just let me know if i m wrong. Thanks a lot for your support.